# Как изменяется размер горутины/от чего зависит размер горутины?

Tags: golang, стек, coroutine

Не могу понять от чего зависит размер горутины. Уже прочитал кучу статей о том, как для нее увеличивается размер стека и тп. Если я правильно понял, то стек может переполниться, если я буду использовать в горутине данные, вес которых больше, чем максимально возможный размер горутины.
Я запускал пример кода, который это демонстрирует, возвращая в рекурсивной функции числа до 1e-08. Действительно падает ошибка. Окей, но почему она не падает, когда я в переменную присваиваю массив байт прочтенного файла, размер которого 1,6 гб, при том, что максимальный размер горутины 1гб?
Моя версия го 1.18

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Из файла ты читаешь не array, а slice. Slice это просто указатель на массив в куче.

Comment: Вы путаете стек и кучу, почитайте разницу :)

Comment: Да, действительно, оказалось, что у меня был пробел знаний в теме "кучи и стека", теперь все встало на свои места, спасибо)